# Can I use the same tcpconnection via different threads without locking or sychronization?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am curious about tcpconnection and its use in different threads concurrently?  I think it is not possible. Is that true?

Think that there is a tcpconnection object which is ready to send bytes to the destination. I have two different threads and each thread want to send bytes to the destination concurrently. Is it possible? And if it is possible how does it work?

Comment: Why don't you look at the documentation of that type and see what it says on the subject.

Comment: You need to make some sort of thread safe queue into which you can enqueue messages from any thread. At the other end of the queue, you have a single thread that dequeues messages and sends them. It's probably worth looking into [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for such producer/consumer situations. Once you get your head around it (you'll need to go async/await though), it makes things like this a cakewalk.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the MSDN documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

You will see the following at the bottom:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are **not guaranteed to be thread safe**.

Comment: And again a case of "I hate documentation, I rather ask than looking up something totally simple and explicitly stated fact".